# Resetting list setting in SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.0

The Play 2 Framework defines default resource generators in SBT:

```
resourceGenerators in Compile <+= LessCompiler,
resourceGenerators in Compile <+= CoffeescriptCompiler,
resourceGenerators in Compile <+= JavascriptCompiler,
```

I'd like to override their list to create my own list of resource generators which contains only LessCompiler.  How can I override resourceGenerators with a new list?

Comment: Why not just comment lines with CoffeeScript and Javascript? (resourceGenerators and entryPoints)

Comment: Those lines are in the main Play Framework build file, which I can't edit since it's part of the framework.  My build file extends theirs and so I do have the opportunity to override the settings, but I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
resourceGenerators in Compile <<= LessCompiler(Seq(_))
```